# propriedade "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" não esta funcionando com postgres

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

A propriedade de configuração do **persistence.xml:**

```
 property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"
```

Não esta funcionando ou melhor esta dando erro no momento do deploy.
Se utilizo como create funciona mas mesmo em desenvolvimento ficar apagando a base toda hora que crio uma nova entidade no projeto esta me custando muito tempo. Se retiro a propriedade também funciona.

```
property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"
```

Estou utilizando o **Banco de dados:**

```
Postgres 9.4.8  
WildFly 10.  
Hibernate 5.2.0.Final
```

Confiuração do properties.xml

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
<property name="use_sql_comments" value="true" /> 
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect"/>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

**Erro que ocorre:**

```
>08:22:22,751 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread
> Pool -- 59) MSC000001: Failed to start service
> jboss.persistenceunit."perolawebsecurityadmin.war#PEROLAWEB":
> org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
> jboss.persistenceunit."perolawebsecurityadmin.war#PEROLAWEB":
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: PEROLAWEB]
> Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory  at
> org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172)
>   at
> org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
>   at
> org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
>   at
> org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at
> org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320) Caused by:
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: PEROLAWEB]
> Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory  at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954)
>   at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882)
>   at
> org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
>   at
> org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)
>   ... 7 more Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException:
> Error creating DatabaseInformation for schema migration   at
> org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
>   at
> org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
>   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
>   at
> org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:127)
>   at
> org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101)
>   at
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:470)
>   at
> org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
>   at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
>   ... 9 more Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "PG_CLASS"
> not found; SQL statement: select relname from pg_class where
> relkind='S' [42102-173]   at
> org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:331)
>   at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:171)     at
> org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:148)  at
> org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4864)   at
> org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1107)   at
> org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1713)     at
> org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:1821)     at
> org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1707)    at
> org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1550)  at
> org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1538)   at
> org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:405)  at
> org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279)  at
> org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251)  at
> org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:218)     at
> org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:428)  at
> org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:377)    at
> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1138)
>   at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcStatement.java:72)    at
> org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedStatement.java:397)
>   at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:42)
>   at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:64)
>   at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:60)
>   at
> org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:123)
>   ... 13 more
> 
> 08:22:22,757 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
> (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed -
> address: ([("deployment" => "perolawebsecurityadmin.war")]) - failure
> description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>
> {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"perolawebsecurityadmin.war#PEROLAWEB\"" =>
> "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
> jboss.persistenceunit.\"perolawebsecurityadmin.war#PEROLAWEB\":
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: PEROLAWEB]
> Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
>     Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: PEROLAWEB] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
>     Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error creating DatabaseInformation for schema migration
>     Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table \"PG_CLASS\" not found; SQL statement:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifica as permissões do usuário que você configurou no persistence.xml.
O erro está reclamando da  impossibilidade de encontrar uma tabela padrão do postgres, a pg_class que pertence ao usuário postgres. Dessa forma, o usuário configurado no seu persistence.xml deve possuir permissão de select nessa tabela. Para isso, a forma mais simples de conceder permissão é colocá-lo como supersuser no banco de dados. Um exemplo de script de criação de um usuário como esse seria:

```
CREATE ROLE usuario LOGIN
ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'md5a3556571e93b0d20722ba62be61e8c2d'
SUPERUSER INHERIT CREATEDB CREATEROLE REPLICATION;
```